# Problems reading all the files in a directory?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, io, directory

I have a folder with lots of .txt files and I would like to read them. For this, first I'm using some regex to catch only the importat stuff with I will work with. So I'm doing the following:

```
    txt_files =(path, '*.txt')
    important_stuff = re.findall("(\S+)\s+(NC\S+).*\n.*\s(\S+)\s+(AQ\S+)",txt_files)

    print important_stuff
```

The problem with this is that Im obtaining `TypeError:expected string or buffer` Any idea of how to solve this?.

Comment: Can you use regex / glob expansion as an argument in codes.open? I didn't know that :)

Comment: I have a feeling there are vastly easier ways to do what you want

Comment: @newWithPython I bet you meant the indentation to have `load_files` not be a recursive function.

Comment: The `Type error: expected string or buffer` is because that's what `re.findall` (like I believe all `re` functions) expects: **a string** -- not a `list` of strings, as `.readlines()` returns.  Thus, as in my answer, you'll need to apply whatever `re` function you require within a loop or listcomp.

Comment: Per latest edit: each of your files contains a literal Python expression to evaluate?  That's well worth mentioning in your Q's text, if so, because it's really "out of the blue" compared to the subject of "reading all files in a directory"!-)

Answer (score 2):

A sounder approach might be:

```
import glob, re

txt_files = glob.glob('/the/path/ofthedirectory/*.txt')
important_stuff = [fn for fn in txt_files
                   if re.search(r"(\S+)\s+(NC\S+).*\n.*\s(\S+)\s+(AQ\S+)", fn)]
```

That's because (A) `codecs.open` opens a file for reading -- it does not open multiple files with wild cards, nor return file names; (B) `re.findall` works on a single string, and `txt_files` surely isn't one.

This assumes you're selecting `important_stuff` based on **filenames**.  If you're actually selecting on files' **contents**, you'll need to open and read each of the files anyway, so a list comprehension becomes a bit unwieldy and one might prefer e.g

```
important_stuff = dict()
for fn in txt_files:
    with codecs.open(fn, 'utf-8') as f:
        contents = f.read()
        if re.search(r"(\S+)\s+(NC\S+).*\n.*\s(\S+)\s+(AQ\S+)", contents):
            important_stuff[fn] = contents
```

Here, I'm builting a dict from filename to file's contents, to avoid having to open and read each file twice -- once to check if it's "important stuff", then again later to process it if it is.  If all of this doesn't fit in memory, ah well, the double reading may be simpler -- then we'd go bavk to `important_stuff = list()` and `important_stuff.append(fn)` in the `if`, and later we'd again open and read the filenames thus recorded as "important stuff".

There may be more if those groups matched in the `re.search` need to be preserved (to avoid scanning for them again), but that's just too hard to guess w/o further into on your part!-)

Comment: Might be better to `glob.iglob` if there are that many files.

Comment: Indeed @ReutSharabani, true: that would be equivalent (and save some memory), as long of course as `txt_files` is not needed again in the rest of the code after the `important_stuff` is selected.

Comment: Only use an iterator/generator if you have an understanding of how they work :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `regex` (or `glob` expansion) in [codecs.open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open). It expects a file name. That's why you get the error.

So you can't do this:

```
txt_files = [(codecs.open('/the/path/ofthedirectory/*.txt','r','utf8')).readlines()]
```

You should use something like [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) or [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) or [glob.iglob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) ([glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) iterator variant), filter the results, and then open each file.

So you get something like this:

```
# filter to have only txts
txt_files = [p for p in os.listdir('/path/to/dir') if p.endswith('.txt')]
# do your filtering
important_stuff = re.findall("(\S+)\s+(NC\S+).*\n.*\s(\S+)\s+(AQ\S+)", txt_files)
```

Comment: When I try this I get TypeError: expected string or buffer, any idea of how to avoid this?. Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you're trying the part where it reads: *So you can't do this: ...* ?

Comment: In fact this solve the problem: `important_stuff = re.findall('a_regex',
          open('/the/path/of_the_files', 'r').read())

print important_stuff`